# Create and modify files inside ASP.NET 3.5 web application without killing session

Tags: c#, asp.net

An ASPX page has an embedded SWF Object pulling settings from a config file. The web application needs to create and modify the setting files "on the fly".

From past experience I'm aware that creating or modifying files inside a web application will kill the session\application objects as I assume it would cause a re-compile? As the SWF object cannot see server paths, I need the config files to remain inside the web application. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could make it read from some other file.

Comment: aye, but the file needs modifying during the lifetime of the session

Comment: And what is the problem with that?

Comment: it kills the application so drops the session of any live users on the site .. at least that's my understanding? .. it could be it only does this for a web site and not a web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that it's necessarily a best way to solve the problem, but it's possible to partially disable the automated mechanism that based on changes of files with specific extensions in specific folders recycles the Application Domain (and kills your session).

You might want to have a look at [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1310976/2581558.aspx) thread or for a more general explanation [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02/21/ASP.NET-v2.0-_2D00_-AppDomain-recycles_2C00_-more-common-than-before.aspx#440333).

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but rather than having your configuration as an actual file, why not dynamically build it on demand by implementing an HTTP handler (.ashx file), based on options in the application itself?

Then when the Flash app asks for the config, your web app builds it dynamically in memory and just serves it up. No writing to the filesystem is necessary.

Comment: that sounds like it might work and very tidy. thank you for your suggestion.